# execute normal command does not work as expected

Tags: execute

I have this line in the buffer:

`* [X] determine how to add annotations  #a475c217`

I want to change it to this line:

`* [X] determine how to add annotations ==ANN== #a475c217`

So I run this command directly in command mode:

`:execute "normal! $F#<left>i==ANN=="`

However, it doesn't do anything except move the cursor to the end of the line and then stop.

It works fine when I run the normal keystroke commands directly. But I need to insert this operation into a function so I want to get it to work in the context of an `execute` command.

** Edit: Typo in command fixed from "F" to "#"

Comment: You don’t need execute: `:normal! $F#hi…`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I noticed that but OP is pretty explicit about using `execute` and I aims to please.   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to use `h` instead of `<left>`...

```
:execute "normal! $F#hi==ANN=="
```

But if you want to use `<left>` you can by escaping it like so...

```
:execute "normal! $F#\<left>i==ANN=="
```

This escaping of special characters when using `:exe normal` is mentioned under `:h :normal`...

> An alternative is to use |:execute|, which uses an expression as argument.  This allows the use of printable characters to represent special characters. Example:

```
:exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>"
```

...and also under `:h :exe`...

> ":execute" is also a nice way to avoid having to type control characters in a Vim script for a ":normal"  command:

```
 :execute "normal ixxx\<Esc>"
```

> This has an <Esc> character.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I assumed the problem was in the `F#` bit because the cursor didn't move to that part of the string. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm surprised it stops at the end of the line for you rather than on column 9. What happens is that it executes `<left>` in Normal mode literally and (for me anyways) that means i.e. `<l` to column 1, `e` to the `[`, `ft` to the `t` in `determine` then it stops because `>i=` causes an error.